# How to create a dictionary with key as a vowel and value 0?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to do this using list comprehension or dict methods. It should not be a hardcoded value.
It should look like this:

```
{'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'u': 0}
```

Comment: There are a lot of questions and tutorials on list comprehensions, try to do a few searches and see if you cant figure it out. A "good faith attempt to solve the problem" so to speak.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [fromkeys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) method to do exactly that:

```
dict.fromkeys('aeiou', 0)
# {'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'u': 0}
```

From the doc:

> classmethod fromkeys(iterable[, value])
>
> Create a new dictionary with
>   keys from iterable and values set to value.
>
> fromkeys() is a class method that returns a new dictionary. value
>   defaults to None.